# can't tokenize a string and pass it to struct in c++

Tags: c++, string, struct, token

i have to write a program in which i have to take time(hh:mm:ss) as string input and tokenize it using : as a delimiter and pass hours, minutes and seconds to a struct time and then display the total number of seconds. I have written the code but it's giving me error that i can't understand. This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct time{
   int hours;
   int minutes;
   int seconds;
  
   void Print_in_Seconds(){
       cout<<"Total Second: "<<hours*3600+minutes*60+seconds;
   }
};

time Tokenized_time(string str)
{
   time time_;
   // Get hours
   int hour1 = (int)str[1] - '0';
   int hour2 = (int)str[0] - '0';
   int hour = (hour2 * 10 + hour1 % 10);
   int count=0;
   int minute=0,second=0;
   for (int i=3; i <= 7; i++){
       if(i==3 || i==4){
       minute=minute*10+((int)(str[i]-'0'));  
       }
       else if(i==6 || i==7){
       second=second*10+((int)(str[i]-'0'));  
       }
   }
   time_.hours=hour;
   time_.minutes=minute;
   time_.seconds=second;
   return time_;

}

// Driver code
int main()
{
   time time1;
   cout<<"Enter Time- 00:00:00 Formate: ";
   string str;
   cin>>str;
   time time1=Tokenized_time(str);
   time1.print();
return 0;
}
```

and this is the error i'm getting

[image]

Any help?

Comment: A beautiful example of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice. `std::time` already exists as a function and you pulled in the whole `std` namespace.

Comment: @Darhuuk should i remove it?

Comment: No, your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Darhuuk That's what I thought too, but it [complains](https://godbolt.org/z/qdMhz7) anyway.

Comment: @cigien How do i fix this? i can't seem to pin point where exactly the error is

Comment: It's a bug in gcc and clang. They bring in global `::time` function whether you use `using namespace std` or not (which they most definitely shouldn't).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Oh, that's cool. I didn't know that, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe actually not a bug, the standard says any standard header may include any other standard header and this includes e.g. `ctime` which is then allowed to bring in global `::time` function. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6257

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time` happens to be the name of a function in the standard C library (and incorporated into the C++ library), and by naming your `struct` the same, you're creating ambiguity, and according to the grammar rules of C++, the compiler must consider `time` to the function name, here, resulting in a compilation error.

The simplest solution is to pick a different name for your `struct`. You could also direct your compiler to explicitly parse `time` as a type:

```
struct time Tokenized_time(string str)
```

And as long as you're doing it, you might as well [get rid of `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) in order to eliminate more opportunities for a similar kind of a headache, confusion, and unwelcome surprises.

EDIT: it may very well be the case that this is a bug in `libstc++`, but there's nothing you can do about it except to sit and wait for gcc to fix this bug. But you'll probably be able to work around it, like this, much faster...

Comment: You might want to mention that this is a compiler bug. `time` is not *supposed* to be visible without including it.

Comment: In addition to what is mentioned by Sam, you have a redefinition of time1 in after calling `Tokenized_time()` and `print` also is not part of the struct `Print_in_Seconds()` is so `time1.print()` won't work.

Comment: My code worked but it's giving the wrong output. It's supposed to convert the time into seconds but it's giving the wrong answer.  Can you help with that?

Comment: @magmine yes i corrected that print thing. The code is working now but it's giving the wrong output

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. You're welcome to post another question, but keep in mind that you must meet all requirements for a [mre], and all information in the question should be in plain text, no images or links to external web sites (you kind of violated this rule here, a little bit).